# Ajax validate response data that is not an empty page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to populate a page (server side) then fetch content and display in main window. I do not have problems with the Ajax, it is just that a lot of time the reponse data is an empty page `<html></html>`.
When I check in my console ->Network->page.html ,

- Status Code is OK

  **Response Headers**
- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Pragma: no-cache
- Refresh: 1; URL=http://balbla.com/page.html
- Connection: Close
- Content-Type: text/html

Then in the Response Tab - > `<HTML></HTML>`

My question is how can I validate in the success function that **data** is not an empty html page, before running the commands below, otherwise, I will end up with a blank page.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://balbla.com/page.html',
data: 'country=' + user_country,
success: function(data) {

    $pageWrap.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('link[href="css/main.css"]').attr('href', $css);
        $pageWrap.hide().html(data).fadeIn(500);
        $.getScript($scripts);
    });
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    alert('Error Fecthing page')  ;  }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip html tags off your response string and then calculate it's length.

HTML Tag strip function is taken from: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Then in your ajax function:

```
success: function(data) {
if(strip(data).length > 0) {
   // content is not empty
}
```

Comment: Hi, I like the idea behind this one. I tested it and it's ok. sorry for the ignorant question, but here function strip(html) is creating a DIV where response data is inserted and checks for textcontent(no tags), what happens to this DIV after function is complete? is it retained in memory? deleted?

Comment: I thought you need more than just checking data == '<html></html>'. DIV was created as a temporary variable. As it is not appended to DOM, it is removed when function body is complete. BTW: I noticed a few warnings (whitespace, old browser compatibility) in the comments of the question I quoted. You may want to check them

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
success: function(data) {
if(data !=="<HTML></HTML>"){
    $pageWrap.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('link[href="css/main.css"]').attr('href', $css);
        $pageWrap.hide().html(data).fadeIn(500);
        $.getScript($scripts);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks. I was thinking about this, but is it ok to it this way?  $.isEmptyObject() as I read on many posts here, can be used?

Comment: No, since you get the response, that would fail